# Display/print brightness and gamma values with xrandr

Tags: display, printing, brightness, xrandr

I would like to know how to print the current brightness and gamma values using **xrandr**.

I have seen many posts on how to change those values and I can do that but none of the ones I've seen deal with printing the current values of said parameters.

I'm running **Ubuntu 20.04** and **xrandr v.1.5.0**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness
```

or both

```
xrandr --verbose | grep 'Brightness\|Gamma'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!